# Timestream- failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy the bytes range [1, 2048]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

I am trying to insert a record in Timestream table where an attribute value exceeds the bytes range[1, 2048]. Is it possible to increase the range?

Comment: Is it possible to request some code @Anjaneya?

Comment: @AllanChua all I am doing is nothing more than utilizing Timestream APIs for writing the records, that's about it. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/writes.html

Comment: it seems that there's no way as we speak to increase the MeasureValue's size as we speak. Would highly recommend to use another store for long data and use TimeStream for aggregated / numeric values.

Comment: I'm storing a string characters that exceeds the limit 2048. Perhaps a different store now.

Comment: Would recommend the usage of DynamoDB bro! If you found the answer helpful man, you can mark the answer below as the "correct" answer so other people who has the same problem as you can use it as a guide! Hope you solve the problem man.

Comment: @AllanChua I have been through DynamoDB already, I am looking to overcome the shortcomings of DynamoDB. Hence, Timestream it is.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that based on the Timestream [record docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/API_Record.html), the *MeasureValue* can only contain a maximum of 2048 characters; If you are facing this problem, I would suggest to rethink the way you store data as TimeStream is meant for building time-series datasets and this type of large data are better off stored in either NoSQL or RDBMS stores.

You might want to considering swapping the contents of that field with a key that points to DynamoDB to address your challenge.

```
MeasureValue  
    - **Contains** the measure value for the time-series data point.  
    - **Type**: String  
    - **Length** Constraints: Minimum length of 1. Maximum length of 2048.  
    - **Required**: No
```